# Angular: Setting negative value on input range doesn't work

Tags: angular, input

I have an input range and i am setting the initial value in component as negative. But the range input is always to the maximum and doesn't behave correctly. I tried without setting `ngModel` and without `[value]` data binding and it works fine. here is my code:

```
<input #cropZoomerControl type="range" name="points" id="points" [value]="currentValue" [min]="minLimit" [max]="maxLimit" [step]="step" (ngModelChange)="onRangeModelChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="currentValue" />
```

and here is how i have set it in component:

```
public minLimit = -0.1; 
public maxLimit = 0.1;
public step = 0.002;
public currentValue = -0.1;
```

but the `currentValue` isn't reflecting. Setting it to positive just works.